# Can glob be used to exclude only filenames containing letter characters?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to count all files (all of which are images) in a folder for an image gallery. In this folder I have photos named 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, and so on. However, there are a few photos in this folder that have a letter in the filename (example: filename is 12b.jpg or 12c.jpg) in the same folder, but I don't want them to be counted as a file/image in my counting script.

Can I use PHP's glob function to exclude filenames containing a letter, or perhaps include only filenames containing purely numbers?

I think I can use REGEX to do this, but I'm not familiar enough with it to know how to exclude anything other than specific characters, rather than restricting a type of character (ie letters).

Current Code is:

```
// Get Exterior Image Count
$exteriorImgDirectory = "images/exterior-photos/";
if (glob($exteriorImgDirectory . "*.jpg") != false)
{$exteriorCount = count(glob($exteriorImgDirectory . "*.*"));}
```

Comment: Use a grep filter regex from the list glob returns. In Perl, its something like @new_list = grep { /^\d+\.jpg/ } @old_list;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create the right regular expression. Something like this should work.

```
glob($exteriorImgDirectory . "[0-9]+.jpg")
```

If you want to test regular expression, there is some usefull site. An example : [Rubular](http://rubular.com/)

Comment: I was able to get it to work using `glob($exteriorImgDirectory . "*[0-9].jpg")`